# Can't change the background color of a textbox

Tags: javascript

I need to change the background color of textbox when the user clicks on it using

HTML:

```
<input id="inpucountry" type="text" size="50" placeholder="country" style="border:1px solid #0F0" onclick="changecolor('#inpucountry','#ff0304')" /> <br /><br />
<input id="inpucity" type="text" size="50" placeholder="city" style="border:1px solid #0F0" onclick="changecolor('#inpucity','#a4d871')" /> <br /><br />
<input id="inpuloc" type="text" size="50" placeholder="location"  style="border:1px solid #0F0"  onclick="changecolor('#inpuloc','#ff97aa')" /> <br /><br />
```

Javascript:

```
function changecolor(tb, bgc) {
    document.getElementById("tb").style.backgroundColor = bgc;
    //document.getElementById("inpucountry").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
```

Comment: What is not working ? How `changecolor` is getting invoked ?

Comment: the above code is not giving desired results. changecolor() is directly call on the element itself..

Comment: Get rid of the quotes around `tb`, it is a variable. With the quotes, it just represents the string `"tb"`, which is not the ID of any elements in the HTML code provided.

Comment: Any answer actually answered your question?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the id wrong!! and not using that **id**

Take out the `#` before the id, just pass the actual id of the textbox. And use that id as the parameter of **getElementById** rather than the string.

Your HTML code should be

```
 <input id="inpucountry" type="text" size="50" placeholder="country" style="border:1px solid #0F0" onclick="changecolor('inpucountry','#ff0304')" /> <br /><br />
  <input id="inpucity" type="text" size="50" placeholder="city" style="border:1px solid #0F0" onclick="changecolor('inpucity','#a4d871')" /> <br /><br />
 <input id="inpuloc" type="text" size="50" placeholder="location"  style="border:1px solid #0F0"  onclick="changecolor('inpuloc','#ff97aa')" /> <br /><br />
```

And Js code should be

```
document.getElementById(tb).style.backgroundColor = bgc; //note that "tb" is replaced by tb
```

In fact you don't even need to pass the id, just pass the reference to current object

```
 <input id="inpucountry" type="text" size="50" placeholder="country" style="border:1px solid #0F0" onclick="changecolor(this,'#ff0304')" /> <br /><br />

 function changecolor( thisObj, bgc )
 {
     thisObj.style.backgroundColor = bgc;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Passed `id` should not be accepted as string..Remove `"`(quotes) and remove `#` from the passed argument from `inline-function` as you are not using [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which could select elements using `CSS` selectors..

```js
  function changecolor(tb, bgc) {
    document.getElementById(tb).style.backgroundColor = bgc;
  }
```

```html
<input id="inpucountry" type="text" size="50" placeholder="country" style="border:1px solid #0F0" onclick="changecolor('inpucountry','#ff0304')" />
<br />
<br />
<input id="inpucity" type="text" size="50" placeholder="city" style="border:1px solid #0F0" onclick="changecolor('inpucity','#a4d871')" />
<br />
<br />
<input id="inpuloc" type="text" size="50" placeholder="location" style="border:1px solid #0F0" onclick="changecolor('inpuloc','#ff97aa')" />
<br />
<br />
```

Comment: strange I tried the stuff that you have given, maybe some typo mistakes would have occurred. nyways, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `document.getElementById("tb")`, as `tb` is a variable, you should have written `document.getElementById(tb)` without the quotes, considering `tb` contains the element's `id` without the `#` at the beginning.